# Decouple wagtail admin frontend and backend

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, firebase-hosting, wagtail

I am using App Engine for Wagtail as headless CMS.
Is it possible to move the react front-end of wagtail admin to firebase hosting?
I want to use App Engine for API calls only. Is it a good idea?
My users have access to wagtail admin, so I want to unload App Engine from any non-API related things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wagtail admin does not have a React front-end. The only API-powered component of the admin is the pop-out Pages menu; everything else is a standard Django web application, with HTML responses generated by the server, so there is no frontend/backend layer to be decoupled.